# Using select statement inside of trigger

Tags: php, mysql

So i have learned somhing abou triggers in mysql..While i as using selct statement inside the trigger it throws me error ..So after some research i have seen that using select statement and inserting into a variable can be done in trigger..So the code which i have used is

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum AFTER UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW

declare some int;

select a from foo into some;


UPDATE foo SET a = 3 WHERE b = 1;
```

But it throws me error like  `Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare some int'`

Why is it like this ??..Any help would be apreciated..Thanx

Comment: could you please explain a bit what you are trying to with the trigger ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i jut want to insert the data of table foo into the variable some

Comment: you can directly use something as `set some = new.a` this will give you the value of a

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty new.a means the new value wich i et with the update statement after triggr right ??

Comment: Yes after update once you use `new.col` it gives you new value. And before update trigger you may have `old.col` to get the old val and `new.col` to get the new value which is going to be updated

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty can you please post an sql fiddle ..? i think this one needs delimetr

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i would be realy helpful if you post an sql fidle sample

Comment: here is a fiddle with a trigger http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4840/1 update it with your table data and trigger.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty please see this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa9be..it throws error

Comment: I am still not sure about the logic of the trigger you are trying to achieve. Please let me know what this trigger will do exactly that way I can write a trigger for you. Also the delimiter in sqlfiddle is different than that in mysql terminal.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i just want to insert the ites from the table to a varibale ..hats all ..can you pleae help me in putting the right delimeter in sql fiddle..it would be realy helpful

Comment: Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f18938

Answer (score 1):

I presume that the UPDATE foo is not part of the trigger as it wouldn't work within a trigger on UPDATE foo.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum AFTER UPDATE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 declare some int;

 select NEW.a from foo into some;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4:

Comment: i think the delimetr is need to be added..it would be realy helpful if you post an sql fidle

Comment: Quite right. I forgot the delimiter (not for the first time)

Comment: still it didnt works..here is the fidle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa9be..can you pleae post a right fiddle sample